# I am confused about strong induction.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am confused strong induction.....
For example,

We consider $p(n)$:$12|(n^4-n^2$).

Clearly, $p(1)$ is true.
In strong induction, assume $p(1),p(2),,...,p(k)$ is true.
We will show that $p(k-5) \Rightarrow p(k+1)$.

But, since $k-5\geq1$, we have $k \geq6$. Then in this case, do we have basis step $p(1),p(2),...,p(6)$ ? and then do we also have to check these are all true ?

What I am confused about is as follows:

At first, we already assumed $p(1),p(2),...,p(k)$ are all true. Nevertheless, do we necessarily have to check that basis step $p(1),...,p(6)$ are all true ?

Comment: Let $q(k)$ denote that $p(k+i)$ for all $0\le i\le5$. If $q(k-1)$, then $p(k-1)$ so $p(k+5)$ and $q(k)$, and you can just use weak induction,

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to prove that $p(k-5)\implies p(k+1)$, then you will have to prove that $p(1)$, $p(2)$, $p(3)$, $p(4)$, $p(5)$, and $p(6)$ hold. After that, you shall have proved that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):p(n)$ by strong induction. Or you can prove by induction that the statement $p(n)$ when $n$ is of the form $6k$, then when $n$ is of the form $6k+1$ and so on until $6k+5$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119234/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-carlos-santos-i-am-confused-about-strong-induction).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you would need 6 base cases for an induction proof using the inductive step $p(k-5) \to p(k+1)$. The assumption that $p(1),p(2),\dots,p(k)$ are true is not really related to this however. In fact, you don't need that many assumptions, just assuming $p(k-5)$ will do.

In general you may need more than one assumption in the inductive step, but the number of base cases needed is the distance to the 'earliest' assumption you needed, regardless of how many assumptions you have.